# Combining lines using reg ex in python

Tags: python, regex

If wanted to combine six lines (each containing 3 elements) so that the final outcome is a single line with three elements so that the first is the addition of all the first elements, the second is the addition of all the second elements and the third is the concatenation of all the third elements.

For example,

We have,

```
12.34  -79   x
-3.5    23      y
32.2E2   2   z
4.23e-10   +45  x
62E+2    -4     y
0.0    0        z
```

and we need

```
9428.84 -13 xyzxyz
```

Here is my current code:

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
""" opens the file """
import re
""" Imports the regular expressions module"""
# lines = f.readlines ()
lines = list(f)
""" Reads all the lines of the file """


p = re.compile(r'\s*^([-]?([1-9]\d|\d)[E|e]?[+\d]?(.)(\d+(E|e)[-]?\d+|\d+))\s*([-,+]?([1-9]\d+|\d))\s*([x|y|z])$')

for x in lines:
       m = p.match(x)
       if m:
           print (x)
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that explains the *problem* with your current code. Also note that docstrings aren't the same as comments and comments that just repeat what the code said are asking for problems.

Comment: Is it mandatory to achieve the desired result using `regex`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `zipping` the contents of the file so that all number of the first column are on first list, all number of the second column on second list and finally all characters on the third list. Then all you do is simply `sum` the first two lists and `join` the third list that contains the characters:

```
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
finalStr = ""

with open("data.txt", "r") as infile:

   lines = list(zip(*[line.split() for line in list(infile)]))

   sum1 = sum(map(float,lines[0]))
   sum2 = sum(map(float,lines[1]))
   finalStr = "".join(lines[2])

   # Some formatting for float numbers
   print("{:.2f}".format(sum1), end=" ") 
   print("{:.0f}".format(sum2), end=" ")

   print(finalStr)
```

Output:

```
9428.84 -13 xyzxyz
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for a regex in your case. Regular expressions are used to deconstruct strings, not to combine them. If you do not mind using pandas, the solution takes two lines:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table("data.txt", sep='\s+', header=None)

df.sum().values.tolist()
#[9428.840000000422, -13, 'xyzxyz']
```